# How can I generate report using Google adwords api without downloading the file?

Tags: google-ads-api

How can I generate the report `CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` without downloading the file (for example just showing the result).
Here is actually what I do:

```
$reportQuery = 'SELECT CampaignId,CampaignName, Impressions, Clicks, Ctr , Cost '
                    . ' FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT '
                    . ' WHERE CampaignId = '.$campaignId.' DURING '.$date.','.$date;

        // Download report.
        ReportUtils::DownloadReportWithAwql($reportQuery, $filePath, $user,$reportFormat, $options);
        $dataArray =file($filePath);
```

I download the file, then I read from the data to show it up.

Comment: Hello, have you found a way to get Adwords reports in a more user-friendly version than those files ? I'm looking for the same thing ATM.

Comment: @JeremyBelolo hi , i added the way i turend out my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actualy i didn't found a way except that i generate that file then i read from it and i use that result :

```
$reportQuery = 'SELECT CampaignId,CampaignName, Impressions, Clicks, Ctr , ConversionRate '
                    . ' FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT '
                    . ' WHERE CampaignId = '.$id.' DURING '.$date.','.$date;

        // Download report.
        ReportUtils::DownloadReportWithAwql($reportQuery, $filePath, $user,$reportFormat, $options);
        $dataArray =file($filePath);
        foreach ($dataArray as $value) {
          $data = explode(",", $value);
          $resultat[$i-1]['jours'] = $date;
          $resultat[$i-1]['impressions'] = $data[2];
          $resultat[$i-1]['clicks'] = $data[3];
          $resultat[$i-1]['taux_click'] = $data[4];
          $resultat[$i-1]['taux_conversion'] = $data[5];
        }
    echo json_encode($resultat);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After a day I found the solution:

In the source of the lib the method DownloadReport of *Utils/ReportUtils.php* say that:

**Downloads a new instance of an existing report definition. If the path parameter is specified it will be downloaded to the file at that path, otherwise it will be downloaded to memory and be returned as a string.**

You can **set NULL to path** and use the return value

```
$filePath = null;
$stringOfResult = $reportUtils->DownloadReport($reportDefinition, $filePath, $user, $options);

//now you can parse the result
```